# アクションメニューの表記の変更

Tags: android

Android Studioでオプションメニュー（・・・を縦にしたやつ）を・・・ではなく「設定」とか文字表記にするにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 　　　　xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
　<item
  android:id="@+id/Setting"
  android:title="@string/Setting"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
  <menu>
   <item
     android:id="@+id/id1"
     android:title="@string/Setting1"/>
   <item
     android:id="@+id/id2"
     android:title="@string/Setting2"/>
   <item
     android:id="@+id/id3"
     android:title="@string/Setting3"/>
  </menu>
 </item>
</menu>
```

こんな感じで入れ子にはできたのですが、・・・→設定→各アイテムというように階層がひとつ多くなってしまいました。
 本来は設定→各アイテムというようにしたいのです。
お願いします。

Comment: `android-studio`のタグがついていますが、質問内容はandroidアプリに関することでしょうか？であれば`android-studio`のタグは削除して`android`のタグにした方が適切な回答がつきやすくなります。

Comment: androidタグに変更しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` を `app:showAsAction="always"` にしたら解決しないでしょうか

Comment: app:showAsAction="always"にしましたが変わらなかったです。XMLのデザインタブで見ると右上に｢設定｣と出てはいるんですが